# I am editing mouse settings in the registry but they seem to do nothing

Tags: windows, registry, controlpanel

I have made a program to change the mouse sensivity in the same way as you can do it with the Control Panel. 
The changes are made in the registry, the keys at `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Control Panel\Mouse` and they are in fact done (I have checked them from regedit.exe) but the mouse works as if this changes are not made. In other words, the changes do not take any effect, they only do if you use the control panel. Why do they not take effect?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Windows registry isn't something that is refreshed all the time. The changes you made will be applied after the current user (that's why it's HKEY_CURRENT_USER) logs in again, or as you said after using control panel, which will read the registry. I don't know, what language your program is written in, but you should check out this link: "https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms724947.aspx"

Comment: I understand. Thanks for the link, this seems to be what I was searching for. It would be great if there was a way to reload the registry but this will do the job.

Answer (score 1):

In general, tweaking registry settings directly is unsupported, especially when there's an API to tweak the setting.  In this case, the API is [SystemParametersInfo](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms724947.aspx).  In particular, you need to use the `SPI_SETMOUSESPEED` as the argument for the `uiAction` parameter.

> In other words, the changes do not take any effect, they only do if you use the control panel. Why do they not take effect?

Because there's often a little more to it than setting the value in the registry.  Often there is a notification that must be sent after changing the value in order to tell the all the other software on the machine to drop any cached values and replace them with the new value that's now in the registry.  In many cases, the notification will be in the form of a broadcast message.

In the case of mouse driver settings, you probably need to use the `SPIF_UPDATEINIFILE` argument for the `fWinIni` parameter.  You might also need to OR it with `SPIF_SENDCHANGE` to broadcast a `WM_SETTINGCHANGE` message, but I'm not sure about that.